# how to use the iterator in if -else loop with removeAll in java?

Tags: java, iterator, removeall

I have the following problem: I do use iterator in the first part of "if" to remove an element of S, but I don't have a clue about how to remove the whole set S3 from S using the same iterator again in the "else" part. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
public void f(RewritingNode x, Set<RewritingNode>S0){
      Set<RewritingNode> S1 = new HashSet<RewritingNode>();
      Set<RewritingNode> S3 = new HashSet<RewritingNode>();
      S1.addAll(x.children);
      S0.addAll(S1);
      Set<RewritingNode> S = new HashSet<RewritingNode>();
      S.addAll(S1);

      while (!S.isEmpty()){
          for (Iterator<RewritingNode> iter_y= S.iterator(); iter_y.hasNext();) {
              RewritingNode y = iter_y.next();

              RewritingNode y = iter_y.next();

              if(S0.containsAll(y.parents)||y.parents.isEmpty()){
                 iter_y.remove();
              }
              else {
                  S3.add(y);                      
                  S.addAll(S1);             
                  S.removeAll(S3);
              } 
          }
    }

    Set<RewritingNode> removedChildren = new HashSet<RewritingNode>();
    removedChildren.addAll(S1);
    removedChildren.removeAll(S3);

    for(RewritingNode x1 :removedChildren){
        x1.parents.removeAll(x1.parents);
        f(x1,S0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you repeating this line twice? `RewritingNode y = iter_y.next();` is that a typo?

Comment: yes, sorry for that. It was a double copy - paste.

Comment: Did my anawer help? If it did please acceptthe answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the elements you want to remove in a separate list or set and remove them after your loop finishes. In the case of remove all, set a boolean and again, do this after the while-loop ends. Or just add all the element to your remove elements list and remove them after the while loop ends otherwise you'll get some sort of concurrent modification exception.

**Update**

Try to use a queue instead of whatever you are doing here. A queue like [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which has a FIFO order. LinkedList has a [`remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28%29) method which returns the first element and removes it. Use it to fetch the first element and compare it, if you need to keep it, add it to the list again and it'll become the last element. keep doing this till the list is empty and that should do it for you.

This should be far simpler than your code and no need for iterators or multiple sets. If for whatever reason you do need to add removed elements to a set (or event he ones you want to keep) when the `remove()` method returns the element, add it to whatever set you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i can't do that because I want the updated S in the While loop. The idea is the following: S=S1, if(y: sthing) then remove y from S, otherwise put y is S3, S=S1\S3 until S is empty i.e. in the end I should have S=[], S3=[y1,y2,..]

Comment: Eleni, too confusing can you explain in layman's terms what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, I'll do my best. Suppose that S1={y1,y2,y3}, then I set S =S1. Thus S={y1,y2,y3}. Suppose that y1 satisfies the "if" condition, then I remove y1 from S: S = {y2,y3}. Suppose that y2 also satisfies it, then S = {y3}. Suppose that y3 does NOT satisfy the "if", then I add y3 to S3, I set S=S1={y1,y2,y3} and I remove S3 from S, so S={y1,y2}. Now since S is not empty I re-examine the elements of S. I check if y1 satisfies the "if", suppose that now it does not, therefore S3={y1, y3} and S=S1={y1,y2,y3}, we remove S3 from: S={y2}. If y2 satisfies it then I remove it from S:S=[] and its over.

Comment: updated my answer, I hope this helps simplify your code and fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal For loop with index instead of iterator or enhanced For loop, I think you cannot do removeAll while going through an iterator

Comment: It's not related to thread-safety. All access here is single-threaded. It's just that the Java collections are not designed to be modified while they are iterated (except CopyOnWriteArrayList and CopyOnWriteArraySet).

Comment: Edited. Don't we get ConcurrentModificationException?